# listar eventos com Javascript a partir de um JSON na biblioteca Full Calendar (Events)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

Tenho uma variável onde armazena o resultado de um JSON através de uma requisição AJAX, conforme abaixo:

```
$.ajax( 
    {
        url: 'endpoint',   
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            action: 'getAgenda',
            keyuser: idLess
        },
        success: function(response){
            var dados_agenda = response;
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }

);
```

dando um console.log na variável dados_agenda, tenho o seguinte resultado do JSON:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "reuniãp",
    "start": "2019-03-19 10:00:00",
    "end": "2019-03-19 11:00:00",
    "situacao": "A",
    "cor": "#4761c5",
    "Update": "2019-03-17 16:24:00"
}{
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Churrasqueira",
    "start": "2019-03-20 10:00:00",
    "end": "2019-03-20 11:00:00",
    "situacao": "A",
    "cor": "#4761c5",
    "Update": "2019-03-17 18:17:00"
}
```

A minha dificuldade é jogar o JSON armazenado na variável dados_agenda, na propriedade events da biblioteca FullCalendar, conforme abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     header: {
       left: 'prev,next today',
       center: 'title',
       right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
     },
     defaultDate: '2019-03-12',
     navLinks: true, 
     editable: true,
     eventLimit: true, 
     events:[
    {
      id: 999,                     <- id entrar aqui
      title: 'All Day Event',      <- title entrar aqui
      start: '2019-01-01',         <- start entrar aqui
      end: '2019-03-07'            <- end entrar aqui
    },
    {
      id: 999,                     <- id entrar aqui
      title: 'Long Event',         <- title entrar aqui
      start: '2019-03-07',         <- start entrar aqui
      end: '2019-03-07'            <- end entrar aqui
    }
  ]

   });
});
```

Não consegui evoluir o código até chegar nessa parte. Como eu poderia seguir com o código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', dados_agenda );
```

**[Documentação](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/addEventSource)**

Só tem um erro no seu JSON: falta uma vírgula separando os objetos: `},{`

Comment: Eu poderia colocar esse script exatamente em qual local do código ?

Comment: Lá no Ajax, após `var dados_agenda = response;`.

Comment: Perfeito querido amigo, vou fazer um teste agora.
Vou ajustar o meu Json